# How is the item view removed from listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-cursoradapter

I know that `ListView` creates only the needed view items and others are dynamically created as we scroll and the functions handling this are `newView` and `bindView`.but I can't find the function that disposes the items that go out of the view.

I use a custom `CursorAdapter` for my `ListView`.
I need that to create an `ArrayList` to keep the items that are currently on the view. How can I do this or does the `ListView` have such functionality?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know which items are currently visible in your `ListView` you can set an `onScrollListener` to the `ListView`.

```
    lv.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

        }
    });
```

In `onScroll` you can get the first and last visible position (`firstVisibleItem` + `visibleItemCount`) and thus get the items from your underlying `ArrayList` that are currently visible.

Comment: I need to do this in the adapter level not in the view level

Comment: Then you need to be more specific why and what exactly you want to achieve.